# API error : Upload Video from server to Vimeo using PHP

Tags: php, video, server, vimeo, vimeo-api

I want to upload video from my FTP server to vimeo.

I am using below code.

**upload.php**

```
<?php
include 'vimeo.php';

$vimeo = new phpVimeo('Clientkey', 'clientsecret','accesstoken','access_token_secret');

try {
$video_id = $vimeo->upload($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/my_video_path/videoname.mp4');
echo $video_id;

if ($video_id) {

    echo '<a href="http://vimeo.com/' . $video_id . '">Upload successful!</a>';

    //$vimeo->call('vimeo.videos.setPrivacy', array('privacy' => 'nobody', 'video_id' => $video_id));
    $vimeo->call('vimeo.videos.setTitle', array('title' => 'YOUR TITLE', 'video_id' => $video_id));
    $vimeo->call('vimeo.videos.setDescription', array('description' => 'YOUR_DESCRIPTION', 'video_id' => $video_id));
}
else {
    echo "Video file did not exist!";
}
}
catch (VimeoAPIException $e) {
echo "Encountered an API error -- code {$e->getCode()} - {$e->getMessage()}";
}
```

vimeo.php is a PHP library taken from this link - https://github.com/vimeo/vimeo-php-lib/blob/master/vimeo.php

I don't know where is access_token_secret is located.

Because of this I am facing this issue named - **Encountered an API error -- code 401 - Invalid signature**

And if I remove the access_token_secret parameter from **upload.php** file

```
$vimeo = new phpVimeo('Clientkey', 'clientsecret','accesstoken');
```

Then it is giving me exception :->  **permission denied**.

Comment: Tl;dr. Try limiting the code you add to just what's relevant.

Comment: I added the vimeo.php file because there are many other files available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code and library you are using are out of date (as mentioned in it's [readme](https://github.com/vimeo/vimeo-php-lib)). They are for the old, advanced API.

The library you want to use is here: https://github.com/vimeo/vimeo.php
There is an upload example here: https://github.com/vimeo/vimeo.php/blob/master/example/upload.php

Comment: No problem, It's hard to get everyone moved to a new API, but questions like this really go far in avoiding future confusion. Thanks for submitting it!

Answer (score 1):

Sign up for a Vimeo dev account at [Vimeo Developers](https://developer.vimeo.com/), click on "My Apps", and create get your client key and client secret from there. You don't create those on your own; Vimeo does it for you. After that, use OAuth to obtain an access token and secret ([Vimeo Authentication](https://developer.vimeo.com/api/authentication)).

Comment: Hi thanks for answer. but can you tell me ,from where i get access_token_secret in my vimeo account.I can copy client key,client secret and i generated token also but about access_token_secret there is no option to create or copy.